# How do you create an over world styled like Pokémon Black and White, with both 2D and 3D elements?

Tags: xna, graphics

The over world of Pokémon white uses 3D models for objects like houses, and 2D sprites for characters like the player.  What would I have to do to create an over world styled like this?

Here is an example:

[image: 2D characters move around the outside of a 3D building.]

[image: 2D characters enter a room filled with 3D props.]

Comment: This looks like a fairly simple setup with 3D models for the buildings and props and quads for the characters - like cardboard stand-ups. Have you encountered any particular problem in setting up your models/character sprites/game camera this way? Are there any particular steps in the process you're stuck on? As-written right now, it's not immediately clear what kind of help you need.

Comment: I'm mostly wondering on how I can get the 2D character to walk on, collide, and interact with the 3D models.

Comment: Give it a 3D collider. Your visual and your physics representation don't have any dependency on one another.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking for, sort of a "cardboard cutout" effect for the characters, then what you'd do is build your "Overworld" as a 3D world and draw your characters on quads (planes).

Comment: Adding onto what John said, check out how Enter the Gungeon does it - https://twitter.com/DodgeRollGames/status/593625936131653632